# Centralized LSI RAID controller management

Tags: raid, remote-access, lsi

In an organization where the hardware maintenance team is separated from the OS platform and operations team, 3Ware's RAID controllers have been in use together with the 3DM2 web service opened up to the hardware maintenance team for RAID device management. This allowed the hardware maintenance team to do the basic tasks like swapping drives, reconfiguring arrays or maintenance runs without bothering the platform operations team and, most importantly, without having local logon accounts to the operating systems:

[image: 3DM2 screenshot]

As the 3Ware RAID controllers are being phased out throughout the organization and replaced by LSI models, there is a need to have a similar facility for the new controllers which also would support the OSes in use (Windows Server 2008 R2  - 2012 R2/ SLES 11 - 12, CentOS 6).

I know about local management facilities like MegaCLI, StorCLI or the Storage Manager (which is only available for Windows), but all of them require local interactive logons. The SNMP agent seems rather dated, also I have been unable to find a straightforward way to make use of SNMP for anything but *monitoring* purposes. So is there anything available to fill the management gap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MegaRAID Storage Manager (MSM) is available for a variety of platforms, including Linux, Solaris and ESXi.  It consists of a server-side daemon and a Java client, which is not exactly a web interface, but would allow you to manage RAID devices without having to log on interactively:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dell openmanage, if you use dell server ofcourse. You can even install it over esx. A openmanage login allow a direct access to the whole server, but as i read your statement they do all hardware maintenance. Edited: hp got a software like that, but i didnt tested it much.

So, it depend on your server brand if you no longer can do it via the controller software.

Comment: Servers are mostly Supermicro builds, controllers are not necessarily Supermicro branded, so there is no way to use OpenManage.

Comment: @the-wabbit Ok!, well then I will let another user direct to a controller with similar feature, for that I cant help. As I agree that snmp is more for monitoring, and my answer was more a workaround